# UIButton continue tracking even when out of bounds

Tags: swift, uibutton, touchesmoved

I'm trying to track the touches on the button. But whenever the touch leaves the button frame, it stops tracking the touch all together.

I've tried using:

```
override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
    let relativeFrame = bounds
    let hitTestInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: -10, left: -10, bottom: -10, right: -10)

    return UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(relativeFrame, hitTestInsets).contains(point)
}
```

and

```
override open func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {

    let minimalWidthAndHeight: CGFloat = 60

    let buttonSize = frame.size
    let widthToAdd = (minimalWidthAndHeight - buttonSize.width > 0) ? minimalWidthAndHeight - buttonSize.width : 0
    let heightToAdd = (minimalWidthAndHeight - buttonSize.height > 0) ? minimalWidthAndHeight - buttonSize.height : 0
    let largerFrame = CGRect(x: 0-(widthToAdd / 2), y: 0-(heightToAdd / 2), width: buttonSize.width + widthToAdd, height: buttonSize.height + heightToAdd)
    return largerFrame.contains(point) ? self : nil
}
```

and I also tried using `continueTracking(with:)` but in all cases, whenever the touch moves away from the button frame, `cancelTracking(with:)` and `touchesCancelled(with:)` is called.

What do I have to do to make it keep tracking even when the touch leaves the frame of the button?

Comment: add a target to your button for `touchDragOutside` event, that is the easiest way to do so.(https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol/event/1618242-touchdragoutside)

Comment: @holex I want to adjust the background and shadow of the button when dragged outside. Does it mean I have to access those properties in (for example) my view controller using `touchDragOutside` event? Isn't that a bit cumbersome when I have a lot of buttons everywhere?

Comment: if you are thinking in OOP, then you could conclude that the buttons are _individual_ objects and they can (=should) handle these events internally on their own (encapsulating it, if you will), so they won't pollute your view-controller nor increases complexity at all – it is not quite easy to tell what is the best archtecture here, as I don't know exactly what your final goal is.